# Simplesamlphp | Invalid Destination URL Error

Tags: php, simplesamlphp, drupal-10

I'm trying to setup simplesamlphp in my localhost and I installed the latest 2.1.1 version and done few basic configuration in config.php. Then I tried to hit the url getting this below error.

> SimpleSAML\Error\Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
> Backtrace:
> 1 src/SimpleSAML/Error/ExceptionHandler.php:32
> (SimpleSAML\Error\ExceptionHandler::customExceptionHandler)
> 0 [builtin] (N/A)
> Caused by: SimpleSAML\Error\Exception: Invalid destination URL:
> http://myloc_sp_drupalsaml.com/simplesaml/module.php/core/welcome
> Backtrace:
> 2 src/SimpleSAML/Utils/HTTP.php:221 (SimpleSAML\Utils\HTTP::redirect)
> 1 src/SimpleSAML/Utils/HTTP.php:955 (SimpleSAML\Utils\HTTP::redirectTrustedURL)
> 0 public/index.php:16 (N/A)

Note: Machine linux AWS and trying to setup it for my Drupal 10 application

[image]

Any help please.

Comment: This has been fixed after changing my domain url from http://myloc_idp_drupalsaml.com/simplesaml/ to http://myloc-idp-drupalsaml.com/simplesaml/

Thanks!